# How keys are reorganized after C# LINQ convert a dictionary to a query?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I am working on C# converting a dictionary to query :

```
public class myClass
{
    public int my_id;
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string[]>> myDict;
}

Dictionary<string, myClass> dataDict;


var queryDict = (from happen in dataDict
        group happen by happen.Value.my_id into g select g)
       .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value));
```

I need to iterate every element of queryDict.

Before doing the query, for the same dataDict's key, there may be multiple myClass that have the same event_id.

After query, for the same happen.Value.my_id, how the dataDict' s original keys are organized ? They are a list pointed by the one event_id ?

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

Basically `group by` gives you an `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` which is an `IEnumerable<TElement>` ([IGrouping Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), so having this query:

```
from happen in dataDict group happen by happen.Value.my_id into g select g
```

means, you group by `happen.Value.my_id`, so the `TKey` will be `my_id` and the `TElement` would be a `KeyValuePair<string, MyClass>>` which is the items of your dictionary. Since the `IGrouping<int, KeyValuePait<stirng, MyClass>>` which is the result of above query is actually an `IEnumerable<keyValuePair<string, MyClass>>`, so for every key you actually have an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, MyClass>>`. As you can see here, you have the elements of you dictionary as they were.
Second part of the query is just converting the `IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, Dictionary<string, MyClass>>>` to a `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, MyClass>>>` so it's not  big deal.

Answer (score 1):

Effectively, your dataDict is an array of `KeyValuePair` (1-dimensonal array). And your query adds another dimension, so it becomes a `Dictionary` of `Dictionaries`.  But adding another dimension is just a grouping of older elements by a new key.

It's better to illustrate it like this:
[image]

Comment: so after grouping query, one key may be associated with a list  (or an array) of dictionary ? thanks ! For example, <1, <key1 , ...>, <key3, ...>> , it I use "1" as key, I can get a list of dictionaries, right ? How to access the associated <key1, ...>, <key1, ...> ?